# Using "git aws.push" overwrites the database I have with my elastic beanstalk app

Tags: git, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a "comments.db" file in the root of my git repo for a flask application hosted by amazon.

It works just fine on the server - when someone adds a comment to a post, the database on the server gets updated accordingly. However, any time I make a change to some other part of the application any use "git aws.push" to push those changes to the server, the database on the server gets overwritten with the database file on my local machine - so any entries that were added to server database are lost.

It also seems that if I stick "comments.db" in my gitignore, then "git aws.push" removes the database file from the server entirely.

How can I make unrelated changes to my application and push them without clobbering the database on the server?

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, Elastic Beanstalk does not keep old files when you update your application. Only files for the application itself should be in the app. You should store your data in one of Amazon's other database services, like RDS, and user uploaded files in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Has comments.db ever been checked in? I think it would work better if the file where free of the repository, it git would never see it or touch it.

If it's already a part of the repository you can remove it with `git rm --cached`. This will leave it in the working copy where you run the command but delete it every where else when they do `git pull` so do it on the production machine to leave the file.

On each development machine you can create a new identical file used for development and test.

Don't forget to add it to your ignore/exclude files.